# Not able to update to macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, software-update

I am trying to update to macOS High Sierra. but it gives me following error:

[image: Error image]

Comment: I think the installer is the incomplete one downloaded previously. To start isolating the problem, can you connect to the app store? Try searching for updates

Answer (score 1):

I have recieved this error in the past, make sure the time and date on your computer are correct.

You can do this by going into "System Preferences" > "Time and date"